# Iframe, full screen css - why the scrollbar

Tags: css, iframe

I want to make on iframe full screen. Here is the code:

http://jsbin.com/ibopes/1/edit

and here is the demo:

http://jsbin.com/ibopes

Why the scrollbar? For some reason I can't use `position: absolute` for the iframe, and I don't want `overflow: hidden` on body.

How to hide the scrollbar, and why is it there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify `display: block` on your iFrame. jsBin normalizes the CSS for you:

```
#test {  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: none;
    background: #ff0000;
    display: block;
}
```

See the working demo here > http://jsbin.com/ibopes/5

Comment: Great idea. I just inspected the iframe in Chrome, I saw it is `inline`, but probably I was too tired to realize that this was the problem. Thank you BenM.

Comment: So this issue is actually related to JSBin functionality?

Comment: Not technically, no. jsBin seems to normalize the CSS (i.e. add `display: block` to elements) when viewing them inside the app. See line 446 of `style.css` on jsBin...